# initialize base class with variable not coming from derived class

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm trying to provide framework which allows people to write their own plugins.  These plugins are basically derived classes.  My base class needs some variables to initialize, how can I initialize my base class without having to let my derived class feed the variable in the base class initialization?

```
#!/bin/python

class BaseClass():
    def __init__(self,config):
        self.config=config
    def showConfig(self):
        print "I am using %s" % self.config

class UserPlugin(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self,config):
        BaseClass.__init__(self,config)
    def doSomething(self):
        print "Something"


fubar = UserPlugin('/tmp/config.cfg')
fubar.showConfig()
```

My goal is to avoid the need to define the config parameter in the UserPlugin class, since this is something I don't want the user who writes a plugin to be bothered with.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I get that when a `UserPlugin` is instantiated, you don't want the plugin creator to have to pass a config path. But where do you want the config path to come from, then? Do you want to have a default config path? Also, initializing your base class only happens when you instantiate your base class. When you instantiate a `UserPlugin`, you _call_ `BaseClass.__init__()` on it, but you are initializing a `UserPlugin` instance.

Comment: Thanks for rephrasing my question because that's exactly it. I understand that BaseClass is initiated when UserPlugin is initiated.  Bottom line is that I want a clean way for UserPlugin to inherit methods from BaseClass which requires a variable to initiate without passing that variable to the derived class.
What I suppose is also possible is to forget about inheritance and to initiate the baseclass first and then initiate the UserPlugin inside the BaseClass, but I find that a bit ugly.

Comment: But you still didn't answer my question. Where do you want the config path to come from? [I took a wild guess](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9786902/577088), though.

Comment: The config path can come from anywhere as long as it doesn't have to be passed through the UserPlugin class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) to pass any remaining arguments to the base class:

```
class UserPlugin(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        BaseClass.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: yes, I understand, but that doesn't differ that much from the posted code and it is something which I would like to avoid somehow.  I guess I'll have to forget about class inheritance and initiate the plugin class inside the initiated baseclass or something along that line.  Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Pastebin code, how about this? This avoids using a separate global, instead using a class attribute, which is accessible as a member to all derived classes and their instances.

```
#!/bin/python

class BaseClass():
    config = '/tmp/config.cfg'
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def showConfig(self):
        print "I am using %s" % self.config

class UserPlugin(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
    def doSomething(self):
        print "Something"


fubar = UserPlugin()
fubar.showConfig()
```

This was the other way to do it that I mentioned before. Keep in mind that if you want to change the value of `BaseClass.config` itself, you should access it directly (i.e. `BaseClass.config = '/foo/path'`; otherwise, you wind up creating a custom `UPinstance.config` value, leaving `BaseClass.config` unchanged.

Comment: I do understand how objects and inheritance work. My actual goal is to keep the UserPlugin class free from anything required to initialize the base class correctly. This sounds silly and in a way it is, but I want to keep "requirements" to make a derived class as low as possible. It's rather an organisational question than a syntax question.  Meanwhile I came to the idea of making globals of the variables the BaseClass requires to initialize it. see here http://pastebin.com/KfdVYbPz Globals are not ideal and should be avoided if possible, but I think in my case it's the best option.

Comment: @jay_t, I don't think it is your best option. You can just store it as a class attribute. See above.